# Get cancel button reference for DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm trying to find a workaround to programatically close Android Time Picker because it doesn't support hide function and it can be closed only when user taps on `Cancel`, `Ok` or somewhere outside the widget. Is there any way to find button `Cancel` by text and programatically click it?

Comment: why not wrap the time picker and a modal? then you can just close the modal

Comment: Just set its visibility to Gone.  That hides it.  Or use TimePickerDialog, which has a hide functionality inherited from Dialog.

Comment: I'm trying to implement TimePickerDialog, but I can't find hide function. Is it simply `timePickerDialog.hide();`?

Comment: @vasyl You have to search for dismiss() function

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to find the cancel button by text. If you are using DatePickerDialog or TimePickerDialog, these classes extend AlertDialog class, so you can simple use the dialog.getButton function like that:

```java
 DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }
                });

        Button cancelButton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // do whatever you want here
            }
        });

        // displays the DatePickerDialog
        dialog.show();
```